# Testing GWT application on Mobile Emulator

Tags: gwt, android-emulator, ios-simulator

I want an android and iphone emulator to run on windows to test my gwt application on windows. can someone point me to a proper emulator because i've been trying some with no success

Answer (score 0):

The official iPhone simulator does not run on Windows. Seems you have to get a Mac ;-)

However the Android emulator can be installed pretty much anywhere:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

If you point the Andorid browser in the emulator to your GWT application you should be able to test it. You can find messages from the browser in LogCat, watch out for the logging tag *WebCore*. You can even log from within your code and get the output in LogCat, see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html